# DateTimeParse Exception

Tags: java, date, time, java-time, datetime-parsing

I am constantly getting an exception error in my code when parsing a date.
The Date looks like this:

```
Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008
```

This is the code for trying to read it:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Property property = new Property();
property.setSale_date(LocalDateTime.parse(linesplit[8], formatter));
```

Expected result: A `LocalDateTime` of `2008-05-21T00:00`.

What I got instead:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text 'Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008' could not be parsed at index 0

Am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devil is in the detail. You are basically doing it correctly, except:

- You need to provide a locale for the formatter.
- By parsing into a `LocalDateTime` you are losing information and possibly getting an unexpected result.

So I suggest:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ROOT);

    String linesplit8 = "Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008";
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(linesplit8, formatter);

    System.out.println(zdt);
```

Output is:

> 2008-05-21T00:00-04:00[America/New_York]

Your string is in English. It looks like the output from `Date.toString()` (`Date` being the old-fashioned class used for times before Java 8). So it’s probably in English because that `toString` method always produced English output. So if your locale is not an English-speaking one, parsing is deemed to fail, and I believe this is the reason why it did. In this case it’s appropriate to use `Locale.ROOT` for the locale neutral English-speaking locale. A way to say “don’t apply any locale specific processing here”.

Your string contains a time zone abbreviation, EDT, which is part of identifying a unique point in time, so you will want to pick up this part of the information too. Therefore use a `ZonedDateTime`.

### Links

There are some related/similar questions, for example:

- [how to parse output of new Date().toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713825/how-to-parse-output-of-new-date-tostring)
- [java DateTimeFormatterBuilder fails on testtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526234/java-datetimeformatterbuilder-fails-on-testtime)
- [How do I Date format for dd MMM yyyy, as in 01 Apr 2020 [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61884114/how-do-i-date-format-for-dd-mmm-yyyy-as-in-01-apr-2020)

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid using the three-letter time zone ID. Given below is an extract from as old as [Java 6 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> **Three-letter time zone IDs**
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone
> IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, **their
> use is deprecated** because the same abbreviation is often used for
> multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central
> Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can
> then only recognize one of them.

- The second important thing: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).
- I also [prefer u to y](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) with `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
    
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008", formatter);
System.out.println(zdt);
```

**Output**:

```
2008-05-21T00:00-04:00[America/New_York]
```

Let's try this formatter for the same date-time string replacing EDT with the [recommended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) America/New_York:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("Wed May 21 00:00:00 America/New_York 2008", formatter);
System.out.println(zdt);
```

The output remains same.

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.